# .htaccess variables and environment for modularity

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I inherited a very stuck-in-its-place website with no development environment. Among the LAMP stack, htaccess files has been my weakest point, and it appears the last developer did a lot of his work using htaccess files.

I've tried tried modifiying it several times, but I only succeed in breaking it when trying to make a dev environment.

What I'm trying to do is take every reference of my site

```
http://www.example.com/foo/bar
```

and change it to

```
[howeverVariablesWorkInHTACCESS]/foo/bar
```

being being built by some variable. I've seen references that htaccess can use variables, but I haven't seen any I really understand.

Ideally, I wouldn't have to put in that variable value manually but somehow pull it from the file's location, but if that's not an option, altering just one line between servers would be much less of a headache than hundreds.

So, TL;DR
**How to make variables in htaccess files and give them values based on file location?**

And bonus request... suggested methods to really get a decent mastery of htaccess files? I haven't seen a fiddle equivilent for htaccess or clearly written guides as of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the variable values automaticly by this method

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase / 
    RewriteEngine On Options All -Indexes RewriteBase /directoryname/ RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    ###############  SEO     ##########################

#http://www.example.com/hello/booboo/ it takes the url  after .com/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ getme.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

for example if i enter http://www.example.com/hello/bobo/

it is going to replace and take "/hello/bobo/" part now you can use this in .htacces file Also if you want to redirect to another page and filter the variable value you should modify $1 because all data in this.

edit: in that example i get url after my domain and i redirect to get.php
also you can divide the url using split method  by "/"  Let's see the get.php page to understand this method

getme.php:

```
<?php

//we redirect to get in url=$1 so our get method name is url
$parca = explode("/", $_GET["url"]); //and we divided by slash the url.

echo $parca[0];//this is first part "/hello/
echo $parca[1];// and this is second part "/booboo/;
?>
```